# Master detail form

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex, master-detail

I use Apex 4.1.0.00.32 and Oracle Database 11gR2.
I create master detail form. In master form (Order) I have one field (Date closed order) who indicates that Order is closed.
In detail form (Order item) I have field Date closed item who indicates date when single item is closed.
How to create validation when all Date closed item is filled check if Date closed order is empty and display some message?
Thanks

Comment: So Order table's date is filled, you would like to fill the date for detail table's date or vice versa?

Comment: Vice versa. When all detail table's date is fill I would like to fill Order table's date.

Comment: Use a trigger in the detail table and when all the date fields are filled, populate master table date field with dates.

Comment: Trigger is not acceptably solution. I have to solve this on application level, through validation.

Comment: In APEX you have plenty of options in item level or page level, do a check if all dates are filled or not. If yes populate master table field using a procedure or in the same validation of item level or page level.

Answer (score 0):

I solve problem with access Apex_application.g_fXX values. Create validation type Function returning error text.
Thanks Polppan for your effort.